# A problem with thetransformation of integral to polar coordinates

Tags: integration, physics, indefinite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I am trying to evaluate the following integral

$\int\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+h^2}}$

One can clearly see, that this integral is invariant under change of x to y and y to x, so the answer must have same properties.

Transforming the integral to polar coordinates, one gets

$\int\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+h^2}}drd\theta$

This integral is trivial to solve

$\theta\sqrt{r^2+h^2}$

Substituing back to cartesian coordinates

$arctg\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\sqrt{x^2+y^2+h^2}$

Which is clearly not invariant under change of y to x and x to y. But it is really important for that integral to be invariant under such transformation in the problem I am solving.

P.S.

For anyone wondering the bounds of the definite integrals I need to substitute are

1. $\left(-d/2,d/2\right)$ and $\left(-d/2,d/2\right)$
2. $\left(0,d\right)$ and $\left(-d/2,d/2\right)$
3. $\left(0,d\right)$ and $\left(0,d\right)$

For the second case, symmetry is super important

Comment: Your integration regions are rectangular, so the result in polar co-ordinates is not as simple as you write

Comment: Put in all the bounds on all your integrals if you want to have a hope of success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the domain is star shaped around the origin with a boundary given as $r\le R(\theta)$, after solving the inner integral you get
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}(\sqrt{h^2+R(\theta)^2}-|h|)d\theta.
$$
Whether that can be further simplified now depends on what the boundary function is. For a circle with $R(\theta)=R=const$, one gets the value
$$
2\pi(\sqrt{h^2+R^2}-|h|)=\frac{2\pi R^2}{\sqrt{h^2+R^2}+|h|}
$$